# Не выводятся русские символы в консоль при использовании beautifullsoup4

Tags: python, кодировка

Python 3.9.13

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#pip install beautifullsoup4 lxml

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("page/index.html") as file:
    src = file.read()
#print(src)

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
title = soup.title

print(title.text)"""
```

В консоль выводится:

```
Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Р° Р±Р»РѕРіР°
```

В настройки PyCharm лез, в разделе File Encodings всё на Utf-8 поменял, не помогло, других решений не нашёл

Comment: Это вообще не связано с BeautifulSoup или PyCharm. Кодировку правильную нужно указать при открытии файла: `open("page/index.html", encoding="utf-8")`